# MySQL query for minimum and maximum char length of all columns

Tags: mysql

Basically I have a table that have been populated with around 3 million rows, and i need to know each column's char length. How do i get these values in one query, considering there are 138 columns in that table?
The result would be something like this:

```
+----------+-----------------+---------------|
| col_name | min_char_length |max_char_length|
+----------+-----------------+---------------|
|   col1   |      10         |      20       |
+----------+-----------------+---------------|
|   col2   |       1         |      15       |
+----------+-----------------+---------------|
```

Thak you in advance.

Comment: Hint: Your query will contain a `SELECT ... MAX() ... MIN()` clause for each column in your table, with `UNION ALL`  between those clauses. There's no magic making this easy or fun.

Comment: 138 is quite a lot of columns

Comment: Is there anyway to combine with thiw query    SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';

Comment: For fun I would throw the column names found by querying information_schema.columns into excel and concat the min,max clauses etc then copy them from excel to a sql query. At least this way I would be reasonably certain that I got all the column names right without the bother of building a sql statement in sql.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. I guess i was panicked by the number of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any direct way but you can generated a query for the problem like this.

### Solution

```
SELECT CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT( 
CONCAT('(SELECT \'',COLUMN_NAME,'\' AS `column`, MAX(LENGTH(`',COLUMN_NAME,'`)) AS `max_length`, MIN(LENGTH(`',COLUMN_NAME,'`)) AS `min_length` ',
'FROM `',TABLE_SCHEMA,'`.`',TABLE_NAME, '`)')
SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '), ';') AS sql_query
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name';
```

### To increase the limit of GROUP_CONCAT()

The longest string returned by GROUP_CONCAT() is 1024 by default. Because of that you need to increase this limit.

example:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 1024;
```

I hope I was able to help you.

Comment: Thank you. It worked, but it sure generated one heck of a long query. I think it could have been used with    EXECUTE command. But didn't try it.

Answer (score 0):

Glad it worked. The question might be simple but see, there are different limitations on what you can do and how. That is why the solutions are not so 'pretty'.
Just in case you need to run this more often and easier, another solution will be to create stored procedure. But... you need permissions ( the pretty part again )

```
# Use this just for testing, to recreate after making changes
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getColumns;
```

This uses the same solution as above, creates multiple queries using UNOIN and executes them returning the result set.
Another way is to create a temporary table, insert the result of each SELECT, and then, at the end, perform a select on all records, but it may not be as fast.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE getColumns
(IN db_name CHAR(20), IN tbl_name CHAR(20))
BEGIN
DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE col_name VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE sql_query TEXT DEFAULT '';

# Get all columns and use a cursor to loop through them
DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR
    SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_schema = db_name AND table_name = tbl_name;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

OPEN cursor_name;

read_columns: LOOP
    # Concatenate a query for each column
    FETCH cursor_name INTO col_name;
SET sql_query = CONCAT(sql_query, 'SELECT \'', col_name, '\' col_name', ', MIN(LENGTH(', col_name, ')) min_char_length, MAX(LENGTH(', col_name, ')) max_char_length FROM ', db_name, '.', tbl_name, IF(finished, '', ' UNION '));
    IF finished THEN
      LEAVE read_columns;
    END IF;
END LOOP;

CLOSE cursor_name;

# Prepare & execute
SET @sql = sql_query;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

And here we're calling the procedure with the database / table name

```
CALL getColumns('database', 'table')
```